# Counting unique post view by uid

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build a mobile app which has a NewsBulletin feature using a NoSQL Cloud Firestore. I am trying to get the unique post view by keeping the user's uid into an array called "views" and count it by getting the length of the array. Is this recommendable or are there other better solution for this? Thank you

Currently this is the structure of my database:

News(Collection)

-DummyNews1(Document)

-newsTitle

-posterName

-bodyMessage

-timeCreated

-views(array)

-dummyuid1

-dummyuid2

Comment: I have one question. If the same user comes and views the same news twice, do you want the view count to be 2, or should it be 1 as it was the same user?

Comment: Hi dshukertjr, it should be 1 as it is the same user. Perhaps i left out that before updating the array, it should check if user's uid exist before appending to the array. However if you have a better solution I am open to it

Comment: I actually like your idea, and quite frankly might be the easier option to implement as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your solution as it is easy to implement. You don't actually have to manually check for duplicate uids, as firestore has a built in feature that does that for you.

Here is an example:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('news').doc('documentId').update({
  'views': FieldValue.arrayUnion([viewerUid]),
});
```

`FieldValue.arrayUnion` will check if the contents exists in the database, and only when it does not will add the content.

Now, although I am a fan of you solution, and I do use this method for `like` type of feature in my own published apps, there are some limitations that you should be aware in case your app becomes super popular.

Maximum document size in firestore is 1MiB. Since firebase auth's uid is 28 characters long,  that would be about 37,400 views maximum to be stored in a document ignoring other fields.

But if this is a new application, I would not worry too much about this limit. Besides, once you get close to this limit, you should have more than enough resources to pivot to another method that scales.

Comment: Oh wow I am learning something new everyday. I like your solution, it is more elegant

Comment: For counters I really like the incremental feature. You could write the counter to a document property based on the lenght of your array with firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1). Have a look at the distributed counter documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters

Comment: I like @RobrechtVM 's solution as well. Increment is a great one to use for counter. You can explore that route as well.